# Defining new correlation model in gstat package in R?

Tags: r, spatial, gstat, geostatistics

Is it possible to define and use the new correlation model in `vgm` function of `gstat` package in R, in order to simulate random fields?

I need to use correlation function (as suggested [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325052/how-is-spatial-correlation-for-a-normally-distributed-data-related-to-spatial-co) ) for the log-transformed exponentially correlated spatial data. Th options available in `vgm` are "Exp", "Sph", "Gau", "Mat"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add them to the C code in src/vario_fh.c, src/vario_fn.h and the model type to src/vario.h. You can't add models expressed as R functions, but if you precompute them for a set of distances you do approximate this; see the examples at the end of `?vgm`.